# Is there a way for HTML to interact with local/remote Host Operating system?

Tags: html, c++

Is there a way for HTML (a simple page used as UI) to interact with Host operating system?

I specifically mean: Are any engines/frameworks available to achieve following (may be common or independent solution) -

1. To just run commands on the shell
2. If certain C/C++ Operating system APIs have to be invoked
3. If it is a remote system and not a
   web server, but has a provision to install any dependencies for
   communication.

Comment: I think even if it is possible/standarized, no browser implements it, as it is a great security hole ready for people to take. Just image an advertisement installing adware on your computer

Comment: You are basically asking how to create a webpage that can take over any visitor's computer. However, if it's for some internal tool, there nothing is stopping you from running a webserver on each possible host and have your page communicate to it by sending a XMLHttpRequest to localhost

Comment: oh.. I see what you mean..  Would you suggest me to work the other way - host a web browser (html UI)  in the native application?